# How to generate same amount of noise to all the values in the dataset?

Tags: python, random, seed

I want to generate the same amount of noise to all the values in the dataset. My dataset consist of 500 values. I have heard that random seed is used for generating same noise but I am unable to figure out how it can be used in here.  My code is:

```
for i in range(0,500)
    x= x + np.random.normal(0,0.002,1) # velocity
    y = y + np.random.normal(0,0.0092,1) # rotation
    z = z + np.random.normal(0,0.7,1) # rotation
```

Comment: please describe what you mean by "the same amount of noise", e.g. do you mean the same variance or something else, should there be any correlation, etc?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator has a good summary of PRNGs, i.e. the class of algorithm numpy uses to generate random numbers

Comment: @SamMason Thank you for your response. By the same amount of noise, I mean the same variance. For instance in velocity, I gave 0.002 variances for 1 point but I need this amount of variance for all 500 points but I am unable to implement i his logic in python.

Comment: Seed value has nothing to do with the variance, it is used to reproduce the exact same sequence which can be useful for debugging, for testing different algorithms under identical loads, or to pull off some so-called variance reduction schemes in estimation.  If you want the same variance, use the same scale parameter (std deviation) for your normals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you just want something like:

```
import numpy as np

n = 500
x = np.random.normal(0, 0.002,  n)
y = np.random.normal(0, 0.0092, n)
z = np.random.normal(0, 0.7,    n)
```

note that the second, `scale`, parameter is the standard deviation (i.e. the square-root of the variance) so you might want to put a `np.sqrt` call in there is your velocity variance is indeed 0.002

the above uses "vectorization" to generate 500 samples at once, rather than individual calls for each value.  if you instead wanted to generate in loop, you'd do something like:

```
x = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
  x[i] = np.random.normal(0, 0.002)
```

for each parameter, but this is more fiddly to write and slower to run so most people wouldn't do this